# Power set of intervals: terminology

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Let $A_1 = [a_1, b_1), \ \ldots, A_n = [a_n, b_n)$ be some disjoint intervals. I am defining a set
\begin{align}
\mathcal{A} = \{ A \subset \mathbb{R} \ : \ A = \bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}} A_i , \ \mathcal{I} \subseteq [1,\ldots,n] \}.
\end{align}
Can I call $\mathcal{A}$ is the power set of $\{A_i\}_{i =1,\ldots,n}$? The issue is that, when I take unions of $A_i$'s, this is not a *collection* of $A_i$'s anymore. I am confused about how to name such a $\mathcal{A}$. Is there a name for such a set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd call $\mathcal{A}$ "the set of unions of $A_i$s". But it's also the forward image under the union "function" $\bigcup$ of the power set: $\wp\left(\{A_i:i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\}\right)$

As an aside, I'd prefer to write $\mathcal{A} = \{ A \subset \mathbb{R} \ : \ A = \bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}} A_i , \ \text{for some }\mathcal{I} \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\} \}$ , or tidier still: $\mathcal{A} = \{\bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{I}} A_i  \ :  \mathcal{I} \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}\}$.

Comment: Thank you @Mark S. I also feel like with this construction we have a $\sigma$-algebra, so probably this is a special set. Am I wrong?

Comment: @independentvariable You would almost never be guaranteed complements in your set, so this is not an algebra (and since it's finite, $\sigma$-algebra and algebra would be the same). I've actually never seen this particular setup and wondered where you would want to use it.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear but $b_1 = a_2$, $b_2 = a_1$ and so on. So $A_i$ actually partition $[a_1,b_m)$. That's why I thought this was an algebra as complements in $[a_1,b_m)$ also exist in $\mathcal{A}$, similarly $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under intersections and unions.

Comment: @independentvariable, Oh, then yes, it's an algebra (and trivially also a $\sigma$-algebra) on the union.

Comment: Thank you for your time, it was a good discussion =)